# Overflow auto for div with inline-blocks inside

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have next markup:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 60px; overflow-x: auto">
    <img src="/images/thumbs/doc.png" width="100" height="60" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">test</div>
</div>
```

Actually I use jquery ui resizable plugin. When I resize the outer div and it becomes too small I want horizontal scrollbar appears. But instead the label near the image goes down. how to prevent this effect? Ideally I would like to apply text-overflow:elipsis effect to the label also, so firstly it shorts with "..." and then scrollbar appears. But I can't figure out how to prevent the label "test" goes down when I set small width

Comment: create a fiddle of your exact code or try using min-width option: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use in outer div the style

white-space: nowrap;

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 60px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
    <img src="/images/thumbs/doc.png" width="100" height="60" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">test</div>
</div>
```